# How to add a shadow border to an image in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I prepared a square and a triangle in Gimp but I am unable to get a shadow around it. I want it exactly like the image below.

[image]

I tried with `filter --> lights and shadow --> Drop shadow` but it casts a shadow on one side only. In addition on one side there is too much shadow. I was unable to make a shadow on all sides (i.e. completely around the square).

I saw a [similar question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/how-to-add-this-shadow-effect-in-photoshop) here, but it is for Photoshop. I don't have Photoshop.

I checked whether the same procedures exist in Gimp, but couldn't find them. I only started Gimp a few days back. Can someone please tell me how to achieve this in Gimp?

Comment: Probably the closest thing to Photoshop's "Distance=0" is Gimp's "offsetx=0,offsety=0"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setting for the *Filter - Lights and Shadow - Drop Shadow* tool to achieve a shadow around a selected object are as follows:

[image]

- **Offset X:** *how much the shadow moves to the right*
- **Offset Y:** *how much the shadow moves down*
- **Blur radius:** *how "thick" the shadow will be*
- **Color:** *Pick a color to be used for the shadow*
- **Opacity:** *Transparency ("darkness") of the shadow (100: full opaque / 0: invisible)*

With the settings above I made a grey shadow around the blue box:

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer, but I believe it requires the installation of script-fu plugins, correct?

Comment: After some research: there is a built in *Drop Shadow* in Gimp 2.8. and an additional FX-Foundry *Drop Shadow* filter (no idea how they are different).

Comment: I need to upgrade my GIMP! Thanks for the info!

Comment: This answer is still very useful. Thanks.