# Creating series of horizontal lines in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, line-height

I want to create this final output of image as in this [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13538/13835), so first I need to create horizontal lines. I am very new to photoshop and a bit aware of Gimp. As I see every answer is in photoshop. Even the first question I have asked was on gimp which already has an answer for photoshop( my [first question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19607/13835) on graphics designing). So, I have decided to start with photoshop. But I am stuck at the first task itself :( Can someone help me with creating series of horizontal lines as in that answer. I tried according to this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOt9KTKXxx8), but ended up with below lines which has gaps between two lines instead of thickness of each line.

Here is what I currently have.

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to achieve thick horizontal lines pattern?

Comment: This question is really vague. Drawing lines is a basic functionality of most any graphic design software and can be done a whole number of ways. What have you tried thus far? What isn't working for you? What are you confused about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you want a 2 pixel line and a 4 pixel gap.

1. Create a new image that is 1 pixel wide by 6 pixels in height, transparent background.
2. Take the pencil tool and set it to 1 pixel, this should be a square
3. Zoom in with Ctrl+Plus / Cmd+Plus until the grid appears
4. Pencil the very top with two 1 pixel points
5. You should now have 2 solid pixels followed by 4 pixels
6. Select All (Ctrl+A / Cmd+A) and then do Edit -> Define Pattern

Now open any photoshop image and you can select an area and do Edit -> Fill -> change setting to Use Pattern -> Choose your newly created pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Create a horizontal line of your desired thickness.
[image: horizontal line]

Select the layer with your line and while holding down the *alt or option* key go to **Edit -> Free Transform** or use the shortcut command alt/option + cmd/ctrl + T. The use of the alt key simply tells Photoshop you want to duplicate the object along with transforming it.

You will see the transform controls appear. You should then move the horizontal line to a desired distance. Accept the changes by hitting enter or return
[image: Horizontal line transform]

Photoshop then saves your Transformation in a neat process called Transform Again (in the Edit Menu). Note that you will have to hold down the **alt/option key again** to duplicate the result instead of just repeating the transformation. It is much easier to use the **Shift + cmd/ctrl + alt/option + T** to quickly duplicate multiple lines to your heart's content.

[image: Transform Again]

### Result:

[image: Result]